# React Native TextInput - Scroll to left when value is updated

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a single line `TextInput` that can be updated via other parts of the UI.

My issue is that sometimes, the text can be long. And in this case, when I update the `value`, the `TextInput` scrolls all the way to the end of its content. I need the `TextInput` to stay pegged to the left when it is updated.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Expo SDK 37, React Native 0.61, React 16.9

Comment: Do you set it's width?

Comment: can you add screenshot here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to move the "visible text" to the beginning of the `TextInput`, but only when you set value via props (I assume that, while typing, users will be able to see last portion of the string).

If this is your issue, I managed to fix it sometimes ago with the following code (this.input is the ref to your TextInput)

```
 if (this.input) {
   this.input.setNativeProps({
     selection: {
       start: 0,
       end: 0
     }
   });
 }
```

Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: This worked. The only issue was that after setting selection to 0, typing in the input field would only allow characters to be put in the 0 position. While the user is typing, I had to add     `input?.setNativeProps({ selection: null })`

Comment: Yup, you need to "undo" it for letting user typing. I use it in a case where I just set the value via prop without allowing editing :)